# How to pass parameter in onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

The code below is calling In index.html

```
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/px.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var newGame = new px1("black");
        new px1Generator(newGame);
    </script>
```

the code below is in px.js

```
var px1 = function (color) {
   if (color == "white") {
        this.x = "100";
   } else if (color == "black") {
        this.x = "900";
   }};
var px1Generator= function (px1obj) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("#mainGame").append("<div class='pawn white'></div>");
    }
    //for 10 object upon add onClickEvent
    $(".pawn.white").on("click", function (event, px1obj) {
       alert(px1obj.x)
    });
};
```

I want to send 100 or 900 to onclick function, how to do it ?
The error accord when user clicks on divs

Comment: Did you try `this.x`?

Comment: Yes i try it but is not true, this.x is point to div object, for example $(this).hasClass("pawn"); will return "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the px1obj param from the on click callback function signature, because you are overriding it.

px1obj already exists in the px1Generator function scope, and you are overriding it inside the onclick callback scope.

```js
$(function() {
  function px1(color) {
     if (color == "white") {
          this.x = "100";
     } else if (color == "black") {
          this.x = "900";
     }};
  function px1Generator(px1obj) {
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          $("#mainGame").append("<div class='pawn white'>a</div>");
      }
      //for 10 object upon add onClickEvent
      $(".pawn.white").on("click", function (event) {
         console.log(px1obj.x)
      });
  };

  var a = new px1("black");

  px1Generator(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainGame"></div>
```

Comment: `var px1 = function px1(color) {` ..?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan cuz I copy pasted his code, fixed, thanks

Comment: another way is to use data in  .on( events, selector, data, handler(eventObject) ), Isint it !?

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here. Firstly, when you run your code right now you'll see this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: px1 is not a constructor

This is because you're trying to instantiate the function before it exists. You need to either define your functions first, or change to use explicit function definitions.

Secondly, the problem itself it because you've redefined `px1obj` as a parameter on the `click` event handler which will never be defined. This hides the `px1obj` defined in the outser scope. To fix this simply remove that parameter from the event handler:

```js
var newGame = new px1("black");
new px1Generator(newGame);

function px1(color) {
  if (color == "white") {
    this.x = "100";
  } else if (color == "black") {
    this.x = "900";
  }
};

function px1Generator(px1obj) {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#mainGame").append("<div class='pawn white'></div>");
  }
  //for 10 object upon add onClickEvent
  $(".pawn.white").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(px1obj.x)
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pawn white">pawn white</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand this part _This is because you cannot instantiate a named function using new. You have to use an explicit function definition for that._! Could you explain!

Comment: Sorry - it was bad wording on my part. I updated it.

Comment: Yeah now it's clear! In the previous version it was as if you said: _var SomeClass = function () ... is not possible_ which is wrong!